Which Command Can I Use To Run A Single Unit Test in Zend PHP
I am new to Zend PHP and I am trying to run just one test out of all my tests. I can't seem to find a command for that. For instance how do I run testDoSomething out of all the numerous test that I have in my codebase.
I am currently using this command to run my test
phpunit --testdox --verbose -c tests

You can use
phpunit --testdox --verbose -c tests --filter testDoSomething

To run only the testDoSomething tests
